# C# - refresh textbox while typing value

Tags: c#, windows, forms, textbox

How can i make auto refresh textbox while typing value like this?
[image]

i tried to do the same but it did not work. i always to hit ENTER to refresh or click on up/down arrows to refresh the value

[image]

here is the code

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            double a = double.Parse(s1.Text); //textbox 1
            double b = double.Parse(s2.Text); //textbox 2

            double s = a * b;
            resultSpeed.Text = "" + s; //s is the result
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input the number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ValueChanged` is fired when you hit enter or focus off, use keyup so the value changes on each key stroke.

Comment: Subscribe to a different event: PreviewKeyDown

Comment: Talking about text boxes but actually using numericUpDown components...

Comment: yeah i know. i just called it for textbox

Comment: @artm the event KeyUp worked. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use event KeyUp. It will trigger every time you put a symbol.

ValueChanged isn't working because it only triggers when you are done with editing - you press enter or change focus.

So basically change your event from ValueChanged to KeyUp.

I'm not posting any code because the only change will be subcribing to other event. Your function is fine, however you should change its name :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. i tried KeyUp event and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Put your code into textbox's TextChanged Event.

Like this

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculate();
        }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculate();
    }

    private void calculate()
    {
        double a = 0, b = 0, demo;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out demo))
            a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text); //textbox 1
        if (double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out demo))
            b = double.Parse(textBox2.Text); //textbox 2

        double s = a * b;
        textBox3.Text = s.ToString(); //s is the result
    }
```